# How to merge elements from one array into another one?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have two arrays with the following structure

```
array
  'main' => array
     'firstYearStudents' => array
        0 => '10'
        1 => '12'

     'secondYearStudents' => array
        0 => '8'
        1 => '9'

  'total' => array
     'totalFirstYear' => '22'
     'totalSecondYear' => '17'
```

But I'd like to get the following one

```
array
  'main' => array
     'firstYearStudents' => array
        0 => '10'
        1 => '12'
        2 => '22'

     'secondYearStudents' => array
        0 => '8'
        1 => '9'
        2 => '17'
```

But I don't understand how to attach the values from the 'total' array to the values from the 'main' array. 
Could you tell me in which direction I should move?

EDIT:
What if I have the following keys along with the aforementioned ones?

```
array
  'main' => array
     'firstYearStudents' => array
        0 => '10'
        1 => '12'

     'secondYearStudents' => array
        0 => '8'
        1 => '9'

     'programCode' => array
        0 => '03.02.01'
        1 => '03.01.01'

  'total' => array
     'totalFirstYear' => '22'
     'totalSecondYear' => '17'
     'programCode' => '-'
```

Then the required structure should look something like this

```
array
  'main' => array
     'firstYearStudents' => array
        0 => '10'
        1 => '12'
        2 => '22'

     'secondYearStudents' => array
        0 => '8'
        1 => '9'
        2 => '17'

     'programCode' => array
        0 => '03.02.01'
        1 => '03.01.01'
        2 => '-'
```

I've tried the following but I got the named keys so I can't access these keys.

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($studentsEditInfo['main'] as $values) {
    $studentsEditInfo['main'] = array_merge($values, $studentsEditInfo['total'][$i]);
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Use php.... array_push function

Comment: We should, instead, help you to fix the code that generates your input data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just map the main array and push the sum of its elements:

```
$array['main'] = array_map(static function($counts) {
    $sum = ctype_digit(implode('', $counts)) ? array_sum($counts) : '-';

    return array_merge($counts, [$sum]);
}, $array['main']);
```

The value of the `main` key would be what you actually need:

```
array(2) {
    ["firstYearStudents"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0] => int(10)
      [1] => int(12)
      [2] => int(22)
    }
    ["secondYearStudents"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0] => int(8)
      [1] => int(9)
      [2] => int(17)
    }
    ["programCode"]=>
    array(3) {
      [0] => string(8) "03.02.01"
      [1] => string(8) "03.01.01"
      [2] => string(1) "-"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you help me? Your solution is great but the requirements have changed a bit. And now if I follow your answer I'll get an error.

Comment: Check my updated answer.. it should work. However, next time you should probably ask another question instead of unapproving solutions that answered a previous state of your question.

Comment: Ok, but what If I have any string value instead of a simple dash sign?

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to move these two properties, this should be a simple solution:

```php
$data = [
    'main' => [
        'firstYearStudents' => [
            '10',
            '12'
        ],
        'secondYearStudents' => [
            '8',
            '9'
        ]
    ],
    'total' => [
        'totalFirstYear' => '22',
        'totalSecondYear' => '17'
    ]
];

$data['main']['firstYearStudents'][] = $data['total']['totalFirstYear'];
$data['main']['secondYearStudents'][] = $data['total']['totalSecondYear'];
```

You should be able to expand that to cover more years if necessary, or eventually write a loop to manage as many years as you need.

Comment: I've tried your answer but I wasn't succeed in writing a working loop. I don't know how to access the indexes of my "total" array inside the foreach loop of my "main" array.